# Json response not showing up the value in textbox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo, getjson

I am trying to fetch the value from mysql database based on the Food item selected in the Food item texbox and display it in Unit price textbox. I have used the blur event on the Food item textbox to call getJSON method and fetch the value from the DB.
I can see the response returned from getJSON in the Firebug but the response is not displayed in the textbox. The code is wriiten below

```
<div class='col-sm-3'>    
  <div class='form-group'>
    <label>Food Item</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="item_name" name="itemname" autocomplete="off" size="30" type="text" required="true"/>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
<div class='col-sm-1'>    
   <div class='form-group'>
     <label>Quantity</label>
     <input class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" autocomplete="off"       type="number" min="1" max="100" required="true"/>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
 <div class='col-sm-1'>    
   <div class='form-group'>
     <label>Unit price </label>
     <input class="form-control" id="unit_price" name="unitfoodprice" type="number" />
   </div>
 </div> 

 <div class="col-md-1"></div>
   <div class='col-md-1'>
     <div class='form-group'>
      <br>
      <button type="button" id="additems" name="additems" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add Items</button> 
     </div>
    </div>                                                      
  </div
```

My Jquery code is

```
//To get the food item price
     $(document).ready(function() {

         $('#item_name').blur(function() {

            if(  $("#item_name").val() !== "" )
         {
            //To pass the customer details and fetch related details
            $.getJSON("getfooditemprice.php", {fooditemname: $('#item_name').val()}, function(data){

                            if(data === "empty")
                           {
                              //$('#myModal').hide(); 
                              alert('No Price exists for the particular Food item');                        
                              $("#item_name").val('');
                              $("#item_name").focus();
                              return false;                         
                           }
                            var foodprice = data['price'];
                            $('#unit_price').val(foodprice );

                    });                   

         }

      });
});
```

My php code is

```
require 'core/init.php';

if (isset($_REQUEST['fooditemname'])) {

$query = $_REQUEST['fooditemname'];
    $sel_fooditemprice = "SELECT price FROM fooddetails WHERE itemname = '$query'";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sel_fooditemprice);
    $stmt->execute();

    //this is how to get number of rows returned
    $num = $stmt->rowCount();
     if ($num) 
    {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $array[] = $row['price'];
        }
        echo json_encode ($array); //Return the JSON Array
    } 
    else 
   {
        $array[] = "No Price exists for this food item";
        echo json_encode($array);
   }
}
```

Comment: Is the issue only with unit_price or with all of the textboxes?

Comment: As you provided, unit_price `textbox` as `number`, and the json result might come as string. Please try changing the type of the output ti `(int)`

Comment: @AppleBud -- I am trying to fill only the unit_price textbox and also the issue is only with unit_price

Comment: @prava I changed the input type="text" in html but still no luck

Comment: Please check what value is coming for `foodprice` this variable

Comment: When I alert the foodprice it shows null but in the firebug I can see the response as ["20.00"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var foodprice = data['price'];
$('#unit_price').val(foodprice );
```

data is a JSON Object, so you need to parse it and then assign every price to some html elements, example:

```
$.getJSON("getfooditemprice.php", {fooditemname: $('#item_name').val()}, function(json){
    if(json.length == 0){ //check if is data returned
        //$('#myModal').hide();
        alert('No Price exists for the particular Food item');
        $("#item_name").val('');
        $("#item_name").focus();            
    }else{
        $.each(json, function(i, item) {
            price = item;
            //do sometinh with price
            //example
            alert(price);
        });​
    }
});
```

then edit you php script and change:

```
$array[] = "No Price exists for this food item";
```

to this:

```
$array[] = "";
```

This because `if(json.length == 0)` will be always false because that message is one item.

Comment: Implemented your code but an illegal character error is thrown at alert(price) in else construct

Comment: Thank YOu Cristian for giving insight on $.each() function. Worked properly.